# Best Practice for network operation at regular intervals?

Tags: android, performance

I am making an application which contains performing network calls to look for updates. Can anyone help with some best practices to perform this task. I can make a service to run on background and perform network operation using Handler at regular intervals but this would consume a lot of data and battery. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an AlarmManager or JobScheduler (depending on API level), and pick a sane frequency.  Doze mode will stop you from going too insane.

Comment: Okay. I will try using AlarmManager. Thank you. API Level > 17

Comment: Because they won't fire when the screen is off.  Also, any non-foreground, non-bound service can be killed at any time, so you may lose your updater.  But an alarm will occur (although possibly delayed) even if the phone is off and won't be killed

Comment: Okay. Should i use it with a service or broadcast receiver?

Comment: The actual downloading needs to occur in a Service, because BroadcastReceivers need to finish quickly (they're then killed).  But you need a BroadcastReceiver to receive the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with Push Notifications from any server when the backend recognizes an update. It's better for the server itself to listen to updates at a regular interval of time rather than the app, because of the reasons you listed.

When the app receives a push notification, it would mean that it needs updating.

There are a couple of options for you:

- Azure Notifications Hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/
- Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Currently not having push notification. So will have to go with alarm manager